# How to group and pivot(?) dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
ID  Species Count
1   Pine    1000
1   Spruce  1000
2   Pine    2000
3   Pine    1000
3   Spruce  500
3   Birch   500
```

What i want is this:

```
    Pine    Spruce  Birch
ID  Count   Count   Count
1   1000    1000    
2   2000        
3   1000    500 500
```

So im trying:

```
a = df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount().astype(str)
newdf = df.set_index(['ID', a]).unstack(fill_value=0).sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
```

Which gives me:

```
ID  Count   Species Count   Species Count   Species
1   1000    Pine    1000    Spruce      
2   2000    Pine                
3   1000    Pine    500     Spruce  500 Spruce
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `pivot`

```
df.pivot('ID','Species','Count')
Out[493]: 
Species  Birch    Pine  Spruce
ID                            
1          NaN  1000.0  1000.0
2          NaN  2000.0     NaN
3        500.0  1000.0   500.0
```

Comment: @jezrael LOL:-) take it easy , this site is just for fun to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [94]: df.set_index(['ID', 'Species'])['Count'].unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[94]:
Species  Birch  Pine  Spruce
ID
1            0  1000    1000
2            0  2000       0
3          500  1000     500
```